# What is the concept of namespace when importing a function from another module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

main.py:

```
from module1 import some_function
x=10
some_function()
```

module1.py:

```
def some_function():
    print str(x)
```

When I execute the `main.py`, it gives an error in the moduel1.py indicating that x is not available.

My understanding was that using `from x import y` in module `main.py` brings the definition/value of x.y in the local namespace of main.py. And since both the function definition and variable x are in local namespace of main.py, it should work ok. But this seems incorrct undersyanding. So what is the exact concept here? Any link to officcial python documentation for this concept?

Comment: This should give an error that `some_function` doesn't accept any arguments first of all…

Comment: @deceze That's not the question here. He says, importing a function brings in in the current namespace, where there is a variable `x`. Why does the imported function not use the `x` from the current file?

Comment: In ```module1.py```  change ```def some_function():``` to ```def some_function(x):```.

Comment: And you are right on your assumption about ```import```. The problem is just with your function definition in ```module1.py```.

Comment: Well, now the fixed code sample isn’t demonstrating the supposed problem…

Comment: In a nutshell, each .py file is self contained. Unless you defined a name somewhere in the file (`import` is one way to do so), the name doesn’t exist in the file. Exceptions are only the `builtin`s, which don’t have to be explicitly imported.

Comment: And I just noticed this ```print str(x)``` is also incorrect in Python 3. It should be ```print(str(x))```.

Comment: Im so confused. Its working now. Please can you point me to any documentation on this topic.

Comment: Well, now you’re explicitly passing `x` as function argument.

Comment: Ok this was the original question. Without passing it explicitly why doesnt it work since function and variable both are in local namespace of main.py

Comment: Your current definition of `some_function` is missing the parameter; `def some_function(x):...`

Comment: But x is global in namespace isn't it?

Comment: Within the module it’s global. There’s no cross-module “global namespace”.

Answer (score 1):

Each *module* has its own global name space.

```
from module1 import some_function
x=10
some_function()
```

`some_function` uses `module1.x` in its definition, but you are setting `x` in the *current* module. This would work:

```
from module1 import some_function
import module1

module1.x = 10
some_function()
```

Note that you can't use `from module1 import x`, then set `x = 10`, because that `import` simply initializes a *new* name `x` to have the same initial value as `module1.x`; `x = 10` then gives a new value to the new variable.

Comment: Yes I understand the second part is due to string being immutable. About the 1st part of your answer. Is there an official python documentation for this concept please?

Comment: The second part has nothing to do with mutability. It is purely about what scope the name `x` belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of sounding flippant, the rule is pretty simple: if the name hasn't been defined within the module, it simply doesn't exist.

Look at this module:

```
def some_function():
    print str(x)
```

It doesn't define `x`, so that name doesn't exist within this module. If you define `x` in *another* module, it still won't exist within this module. Even if you import this module into the other module that defines `x`, `x` still won't exist within *this* module.

There's no "global `global`" namespace. Each module has its own `global` namespace. Names are never implicitly shared between modules, they must always be explicitly imported.

<sub>The only exception to this are the [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html), which—for convenience—don't need to be explicitly imported.</sub>

Comment: Thank you. Which is the best documentation on this specific topic?

Comment: Not sure, as this is rather basic and fundamental. Perhaps https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html.

Comment: I have recently got my head around the concepts of mutability with respect to import and from import which was very enlightening. Thanks for the link and having read it before, I didn't find anything specific like how you have answered. Thank you. If you happen to come across any doc on this topic then do share with me.