# Python variable defined with "with" statement - what's the scope?

Tags: python

```
class S:
    def __init__(self):
        sess.do_something()
```

Main:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Session() as sess:
        s1 = S()
        s1.do_something()
```

The above code works as long as `class S` is in the same file. It doesn't work (`NameError: name 'sess' is not defined`) when class is in a separate file.

Is this expected?

Comment: Yes, that's quite expected. It doesn't have anything to do with `with`. You can simply look at the file in which `S` is defined. Is `sess` defined or imported in it in any way? No? Then it doesn't exist.

Comment: Use ```import``` if it is in another file. [Like Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory)

Comment: this how method handle search for reference, in your case: search in  it's scope first, the scope of class second, the scope of module.

Comment: `with` does not provide additional scope. it calls e.g. clean-up method on the referred object (`sess`) in your case. check e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3012921/10197418) post.

Comment: @deceze Please add the comment as answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58450423/476 would do, good enough to be a duplicate…?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing has nothing to do with the `with` statement.
You have simply created a class in the wrong way.
If you want to use the `do_something()` method of `Session()` in your class, you can either [inherit](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp) from it: `class S(Session): ...`, or you can pass `sess` as a variable:

```
class S:
    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session

    def do_something(self)
        return self.session.do_something()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Session() as sess:
        s1 = S(sess)
        s1.do_something()
```